# No CSS being applied in Internet Explorer 9 IE9 standards mode - Official Release

Tags: internet-explorer-9

Downloaded the official release of IE 9 last night and looked at a couple of sites I have developed. To my horror a lot of my sites are loading without any CSS applied when running in IE9 standards mode.

What is going on can anyone tell me?

If I look in developer tools it is like the stylesheet file is blank.

Some of the sites are:

- http://www.shorelinegroup.com.au/
- http://www.mrrental.com.au/

I understand that some of my previous work may not work exactly correct in IE 9 BUT surely the CSS should at least load and be applied!

Can't find anyone reporting this issue either in Google.

I mucked around for about an hour but can not figure out what the issue is.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer my own question. The problem is cause by the character encoding in HTML5 boilerplate.

https://github.com/paulirish/html5-boilerplate-server-configs/issues#issue/15

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? That link is now a 404 :(